# Maintain focused group row

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

Using TcxGrid, when adding/removing grouped columns to the grid, the focused row jumps to where the 'detail' record belongs to after the new grouping layout.  This is fine if the focused row was a data row.  However, it's very confusing if the focused row was a group row.

If the current focused row is a group row, is there an option to keep the focus on that group row after the grouping layout has changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `dcoGroupsAlwaysExpanded` option for your DataController set to True?

Comment: I think you would do best to ask Devex support how to do this.  I think what you need to ask is how to walk the GroupRows of a given data record from the current GroupRow to the previously-focused one.  I've spent quite a while studying the cxGrid source, but it's not at all obvious to me at any rate how to do this.

Comment: Thx, was hoping there was an option already available.  Will ask DevEx support then.